# asp.net mvc 5 sent email attachments are damaged

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, system.net.mail

I am trying to send an email using the method described in this [tutorial](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/268/how-to-send-email-in-asp-net-mvc) with a model structure form this [tutorial](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/259/asp-net-mvc-5-with-ef-6-working-with-files) and im partially successfull in doing so. The only issue I am having is the fact that files sent as attachments are damaged. I have tried to get it working in so many ways that I lost count. Obviously haven't been trying hard enough since I didn't find the answer, but decided to ask while I continue looking for an answer.

My controller action is as follows:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index( [Bind(Include = "column names..")] Contact contact, HttpPostedFileBase upload){ 
  if (ModelState.IsValid && status)
  {
    var message = new MailMessage();
    if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0) 
    {
       // 4MB -> 4000 * 1024
       const int maxFileSize = 4096000;
       if (upload.ContentLength < maxFileSize) 
       {
         var document = new File 
         {
           FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName),
           FileType = FileType.Document,
           ContentType = upload.ContentType
         };
         var supportedTypes = new[] {"doc", "docx", "pdf", "jpg"};
         var extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(document.FileName);
         if (extension != null)
         {
            var fileExt = extension.Substring(1);
            if (!supportedTypes.Contains(fileExt))
            {
               ModelState.AddModelError("document", "Wrong format");
               return View();
            }
            //this is the line that sends damaged attachments, 
            //I believe I should be using document in some way (using reader bit below), 
            //but whatever I use the code complains or crashes.
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(upload.InputStream, Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName)));

            using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
            {
            document.Content = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
            //message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(document.Content, document.FileName));
            }
            contact.Files = new List<File> {document};
        }
      }else
      { 
        ModelState.AddModelError("document", "File too big. Max 4MB.");
      }
   }
```

EDIT: A lot of times the code cannot  find the file, how do I make sure I give it correct path each time?